# Can't group values in a Pandas column by a month

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the number of instances in the timelog, grouped by month. I have the following Pandas column:

```
print df['date_unconditional'][:5]

0    2018-10-15T07:00:00
1    2018-06-12T07:00:00
2    2018-08-28T07:00:00
3    2018-08-29T07:00:00
4    2018-10-29T07:00:00
Name: date_unconditional, dtype: object
```

Then I transformed it to datetime format

```
df['date_unconditional'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unconditional'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
print df['date_unconditional'][:5]


0   2018-10-15
1   2018-06-12
2   2018-08-28
3   2018-08-29
4   2018-10-29
Name: date_unconditional, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And then I tried counting them, but I keep getting a mistake

```
df['date_unconditional'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unconditional'], errors='coerce')
print df['date_unconditional'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `key` in [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['date_unconditional'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unconditional'], errors='coerce')
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M',key='date_unconditional'))['date_unconditional'].count())
2018-06-30    1
2018-07-31    0
2018-08-31    2
2018-09-30    0
2018-10-31    2
Freq: M, Name: date_unconditional, dtype: int64
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then is possible use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) - difference with between is `count` excluded missing values, `size` not.

```
df['date_unconditional'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unconditional'], errors='coerce')
print (df.set_index('date_unconditional').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).size())
2018-06-30    1
2018-07-31    0
2018-08-31    2
2018-09-30    0
2018-10-31    2
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```